# Reading multipart/form-data aws lamda .NET core

Tags: c#, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, multipartform-data

My AWS lambda function implemented in .NET Core 3.1 and deployed behind AWS API gateway. I have enabled multipart/form-data in API gateway. Using postman I am able invoke the function handler with a form parameter and excel file. I am receiving file and other form content in base64 format.

I am using postman and sending two form fields.
file_data -> Attached Excel file
ConnectionId -> a string parameter

[image]

API gateway is receiving below request.

```
{
"Resource": "/uploadexcelfile",
"Path": "/uploadexcelfile",
"HttpMethod": "POST",
"Headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,la;q=0.8",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    ...........
"MultiValueHeaders": {
    "Accept": [
        "*/*"
    ],
    "Accept-Encoding": [
        "gzip, deflate, br"
    ],
    "Accept-Language": [
        "en-US,en;q=0.9,la;q=0.8"
    ],
    "cache-control": [
        "no-cache"
    ],
    .................
    "content-type": [
        "multipart/form-data"
    ],
    "Host": [
        "e32uavabf4.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com"
     
    "X-Forwarded-For": [
        "120.138.1.151, 64.252.191.154"
    ],
    "X-Forwarded-Port": [
        "443"
    ],
    "X-Forwarded-Proto": [
        "https"
    ]
},
"RequestContext": {
    "Path": "/qa/uploadexcelfile",
    "AccountId": "575372985953",
    "ResourceId": "z5ia5b",
    "Stage": "qa",
    "RequestId": "41f54841-4205-4427-add1-4581bb8fa3f7",
    "Identity": {
        "SourceIp": "120.138.1.151",
        "UserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36"
    },
    "ResourcePath": "/uploadexcelfile",
    "HttpMethod": "POST",
    "ApiId": "e32uavabf4",
    "ExtendedRequestId": "FdbMlGPYrPEFoNQ=",
    "ConnectionAt": 0,
    "DomainName": "e32uavabf4.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com",
    "DomainPrefix": "e32uavabf4",
    "RequestTime": "10/Sep/2021:18:35:47 +0000",
    "RequestTimeEpoch": 1631298947586
},
"Body": "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",
"IsBase64Encoded": true
```

}

How can I convert this base64 string and read form parameter and Excel file in my lamda function.

[image]

Comment: consider using the custom runtime: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/net-core-3-0-on-lambda-with-aws-lambdas-custom-runtime/ - it will allow you to work with a lambda as if it was an asp.net core app

Comment: unfortunately using asp.net core app was not an option. I managed to solve this using MultipartFormDataParser nuget

Answer (score -1):

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(apiRequest.file_data);
await using var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
```

Then upload the stream or convert the `stream` to `byte[]`